# Can NSubstitute mock a return value based on an interface arg rather than concrete type?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I have an entity, and a validator:

```
public class Customer : IEntity { /* ... */ }
public class CustomerValidator : IValidator<Customer> { /* ... */ }
```

I want to mock the validator factory:

```
public interface IValidatorFactory
{
  IValidator<TEntity> create<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IEntity;
}
```

My mock:

```
var mockFactory = Substitute.For<IValidatorFactory>();
mockFactory.create(Arg.Any<Customer>()).Returns(m => new CustomerValidator());
```

This works when the argument is a `Customer`.

But the code I'm testing passes an `IEntity`, so the mock doesn't work.

Can I rewrite the mock to handle an argument typed to the interface rather than a concrete class?

Comment: I tried variations of the following, which doesn't compile `mock.create(Arg.Is<IEntity>(a => a is Customer)).Returns(m => new CustomerValidator());` the error is `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IValidator<IEntity>' because it is not a delegate type`

Comment: There's no way to have both covariance and contravariance. I believe tests shouldn't impose architecture decisions. One still can write testable code without adapting code for tests.

Comment: @grokky - can you share the code/method under test? I think it would help to if we had a bit more context.

Comment: @AlexandrNikitin Yes I think you're right. I need to rethink my tests. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @DavidTchepak I've added the code under test as an update, but I think I need to rethink everything, not sure this is solvable. Thanks for your help, and thanks for an incredible mocking lib (and thanks to Alex too!)

Comment: @grokky I'm trying to work out how your real code uses the  `CustomerValidator` as an `IValidator<IEntity>`? Whatever your real code is doing, you'll need to take a similar approach in your test. As far as the NSub part of the question goes, I think the main point was making sure the correct generic instance was stubbed, `create<IEntity>()` rather than `create<Customer>` (as shown in Alexandr's answer). The remainder is working out how you want the types to hang together. :)

Comment: @DavidTchepak Thanks for that, I've since solved the problem using your and Alexandr's advice. The problem was not NSubstitute, but the generic design of the SUT. How the types "hang together" was the real problem! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with generics, they don't "preserve" type parameter inheritance by default. Generic type parameters are invariant by default. That means that you cannot return an instance of `IValidator<Customer>` as `IValidator<IEntity>`, even if `Customer` derived from `IEntity`. You need to specify the contravariance relation explicitly that enables you to use a more generic type `IValidator<IEntity>` than originally instantiated `IValidator<Customer>`. Just mark the type parameter with the `out` keyword:

```
public interface IValidator<out T> where T : IEntity { }
```

You can read about in ["Covariance and Contravariance in Generics"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here's the full example:

```
public interface IValidatorFactory
{
    IValidator<TEntity> create<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IEntity;
}

public interface IEntity { }
public interface IValidator<out T> { }
public class Customer : IEntity { }
public class CustomerValidator : IValidator<Customer> { }

[Test]
public void SO_43360005()
{
    var sub = Substitute.For<IValidatorFactory>();
    sub.create(Arg.Is<IEntity>(x => x is Customer)).Returns(_ => new CustomerValidator());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for assisting. Changing to contravariant solves one problem but creates another. I've added an update to the question, do you mind taking a look?

Comment: @grokky Yes, suggesting the contravariance was a stupid idea. You most probably have `IValidator` accepting `IEntity` as an argument. But at least it explains the problem you have.

Comment: Not stupid at all, you taught me a lot. Not sure how to fix it yet, but at least I understand the problem. (And thanks for all the work you've done on the library!)